# How to match html-comment with preg_match_all (PHP)?

Tags: php, html, regex, comments

I have this HTML-document:

```
<!--SETTINGS 
title: This is the title
keywords: dummy, title, longer keyword, another
description: This is the description of the page
 -->

dit is de home dit is de homedit is de homedit is de homedit is de home
dit is de home
dit is de home
dit is de home
dit is de homedit is de homedit is de homedit is de home
dit is de homedit is de homedit is de home
```

Now, I'd like to match the comment at the beginning. I think my regex-pattern looks like this:

```
<!--SETTINGS([\s\S])*-->
```

When I test it in: http://regexr.com?2ucae , everything seems to work like it should.
When I put it in PHP, I get an error: Fout 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Connection lost.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The XPath `//comment()` will match all comments in a DOMDocument.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with your **regex-pattern**

Check your computer for malware and do some research about `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Example: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=476f762a0f84017f&hl=en